# How to make GNOME 3 hibernate from timeout using pm-hibernate

Tags: gnome, hibernate, ubuntu-12.04, gnome3, fedora-17

I am running Fedora 17 with GNOME 3 as my desktop, and have set up the machine to hibernate after idle for 1 hour.  However, instead of switching off the machine appears to be on with the fan running.

When I run pm-hibernate from the command line, I get the expected hibernate behavior.

Also, KDE4 desktop hibernates correctly after the timeout occurs.

So I believe that the mechanism GNOME 3 is using to initiate hibernate is problematic.  Where can I manually inspect what GNOME 3 is executing to accomplish the hibernate?  And how can I modify it to run pm-hibernate as I do successfully from the command line?

Thanks,

SetJmp

I am adding Ubuntu 12.04 tag to this in addition to fedora-17, because I believe I saw the same behavior back when I had that OS installed.

Comment: Are you using uswsusp, tuxonice, or related addons? What happens when you run `systemctl hibernate`?

Comment: systemctl hibernate works as expected.  I can't find any trace of these other two packages on my system, but also can't find them in the yum repos by those names.  In any case executables with those names are not found in my /sbin/ or /usr/sbin.